How to get time differences between rows for each ID and Change in Status in SQL
I am trying to get the time differences per id and status change with the following data:
create table Table1(idversion text, id text, status text,  dt datetime);

insert into Table1 values 
("1_1", "1", "OK",'2020-05-14T01:00:00')
,("1_2", "1", "OK",'2020-05-14T01:00:10')
,("1_3", "1", "NOT OK",'2020-05-14T01:00:20')
,("2_1", "2", "OK",'2020-05-14T01:00:00')
,("2_2", "2", "NOT OK", '2020-05-14T01:00:10')
,("1_4", "1", "OK",'2020-05-14T01:00:30')
,("1_5", "1", "OK",'2020-05-14T01:00:40')
,("1_6", "1", "OK",'2020-05-14T01:00:50')
;

Select * FROM Table1 ORDER BY idversion;




idversion
id
status
dt




1_1
1
OK
2020-05-14 01:00:00


1_2
1
OK
2020-05-14 01:00:10


1_3
1
NOT OK
2020-05-14 01:00:20


1_4
1
OK
2020-05-14 01:00:30


1_5
1
OK
2020-05-14 01:00:40


1_6
1
OK
2020-05-14 01:00:50


2_1
2
OK
2020-05-14 01:00:00


2_2
2
NOT OK
2020-05-14 01:00:10



I can get the time_diff between each id as such
SELECT *,
  dt - LAG(dt) OVER ( partition by id order by idversion )as lag
FROM Table1
ORDER BY idversion;

But what I am looking to do is get all the time differences for the same ID and when there is a status change.
So the expected output would be



idversion
id
status
time_diff




"1_1"
"1"
"OK"
20


"1_3"
"1"
"NOT OK"
10


"2_1"
"2"
"OK"
10




What's the logic behind your desired result to fetch exactly those 3 rows? Why not for example the row with idversion "2_2"?

Because there's no change of status after idversion 2_2. If there was an OK Status after 2_2 for ID 2 then we would have a row for idversion 2_2. If we had more NOT OK statuses after 2_2 for id 2 then we would also only have those 3 rows returned

Firts of all the Id column should be an integer, that will help with the sorting. Next try to split the IdVersion column into separate columns that are for numbers. After that try to use a CTE query or a cursor.

Correct, thanks that was the info. I think I was able to string together the right answer

Fixing the table first as I do have those fields, I just omitted them
create table Table1(idversion text, id text, version int, status text,  dt datetime);

insert into Table1 values 
("1_1", "1", 1, "OK",'2020-05-14T01:00:00')
,("1_2", "1", 2, "OK",'2020-05-14T01:00:10')
,("1_3", "1", 3, "NOT OK",'2020-05-14T01:00:20')
,("2_1", "2", 1, "OK",'2020-05-14T01:00:00')
,("2_2", "2", 2, "NOT OK", '2020-05-14T01:00:10')
,("1_4", "1", 4, "OK",'2020-05-14T01:00:30')
,("1_5", "1", 5, "OK",'2020-05-14T01:00:40')
,("1_6", "1", 6, "OK",'2020-05-14T01:00:50')
;


Records: 8  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


Select * FROM Table1 ORDER BY id, version;




idversion
id
version
status
dt




1_1
1
1
OK
2020-05-14 01:00:00


1_2
1
2
OK
2020-05-14 01:00:10


1_3
1
3
NOT OK
2020-05-14 01:00:20


1_4
1
4
OK
2020-05-14 01:00:30


1_5
1
5
OK
2020-05-14 01:00:40


1_6
1
6
OK
2020-05-14 01:00:50


2_1
2
1
OK
2020-05-14 01:00:00


2_2
2
2
NOT OK
2020-05-14 01:00:10



And with the following CTEs, I have the desired output, for ID changes and state changes only being shown
WITH cte  AS (SELECT *,
  COALESCE(lag(status) OVER (partition by id order by id, version), "init") as last_status
FROM Table1
ORDER BY id, version
),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT *,
  LEAD(dt) OVER (partition by id order by id, version) - dt as time_diff FROM cte
WHERE status != last_status
)
SELECT * FROM cte2 WHERE time_diff IS NOT NULL;




idversion
id
version
status
dt
last_status
time_diff




1_1
1
1
OK
2020-05-14 01:00:00
init
20


1_3
1
3
NOT OK
2020-05-14 01:00:20
OK
10


2_1
2
1
OK
2020-05-14 01:00:00
init
10



fiddle
